# A MongoDB find() that matches when all $and conditions match the same sub-document?

Tags: mongodb, find, subdocument

If I have a set of MongoDB documents like the following, what can I do to get a find() result that only returns the families who have 2 pets who all like liver?

Here is what I expected to work:

```
db.delegation.find({pets:2, $and: [{'foods.liver': true}, {'foods.allLike': true}] })
```

Here is the document collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5384888e380efca06276cf5e"),
    "family": "smiths",
    "pets": 2,
    "foods" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "chicken",
            "allLike" : true,
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "liver",
            "allLike" : false,
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4384888e380efca06276cf50"),
    "family": "jones",
    "pets": 2,
    "foods" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "chicken",
            "allLike" : true,
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "liver",
            "allLike" : true,
        }
    ]
}
```

What I end up getting is **both families** because they both have at least one food marked as true for allLike.  It seems that the two conditions in the $and are true if any foods sub-document matches, but what I want is the two conditions to match for the conditions as a pair.

As is, I get the Jones family back (as I want) but also Smith (which I don't).  Smith gets returned because the chicken sub-doc has allLike set to true and the liver sub-doc has a name of 'liver'.  The conditions are matching across separate foods sub-docs.  I want them to match as a pair on a foods document.

This code is not the real use case, obviously.  I have one, but I've simplified it to protect the innocent...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the ideal use case for the `$elemMatch` operator, which matches more than one component **within an array element**:

```
db.delegation.find({pets:2, foods: { $elemMatch: {name: 'liver', allLike: true}}})
```

On the other hand, the `$and` operator is unsuitable here, because it can match against **different** elements of an array.

Comment: Bonus points for not only being right, but also fast.  13 minutes.  Thanks very much!